# Can I imprint my Commander onto Mimic Vat, and still take it back to the Command Zone?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I am playing a Sharuum the Hegemon EDH deck, can I let my commander go to the graveyard, exile it under [Mimic Vat](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mimic%20Vat) and then put it into the command zone but still have it imprinted, or does the fact that that is a replacement effect make it so it isn't imprinted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

> 607.2a If an object has an activated or triggered ability printed on it that instructs a player to exile one or more cards and an ability printed on it that refers either to “the exiled cards” or to cards “exiled with [this object],” these abilities are linked. The second ability refers only to cards in the exile zone that were put there as a result of an instruction to exile them in the first ability.

There are no cards in the exile zone, so there is nothing to copy.

Comment: I'd mention something about not being able to have a cake and eat it too, but that expression never made any sense to me.

Comment: the original quote was "... eat your cake and have it too" some how it got reversed while retaining the original  meaning!